# I can't write in input element (just happens in Firefox)

Tags: html, firefox

I can't write in input element (problem just in Firefox). Works fine in Chrome.

I have an input, once I click on it the cursor is shown but when I press a key (in my keyboard) the cursor goes away and the writting is not working at all.

**Real HTML**

```
<div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_localidad_value" id="edit-field-localidad-value-wrapper">
         <label for="edit-field-localidad-value" style="display: none;">City</label>
         <div class="views-widget">
              <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-localidad-value">
                    <input type="text" class="form-text" maxlength="128" size="30" value="" name="field_localidad_value" id="edit-field-localidad-value">
              </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: holy batman that `class` name -> `views-widget-filter-field_localidad_value`

Comment: @Mr.Alien any problem with this class name at all?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was:

```
input{
padding: 15px;
}
```

which I change to

```
input{
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
}
```